How do I fix this "Workspace.test.Script:6: attempt to index nil with 'Playing'" problem?
so the output says "Workspace.test.Script:6: attempt to index nil with 'Playing'"
this is my whole code
local start = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("start")
local endanim = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("end1")
local veryend = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("veryend")

if script.Parent then
    if start.Playing == false then
        start:Play()
    elseif start.Playing == true then
        wait(2)
        start:Stop()
        endanim:Play()
    elseif endanim.Playing == true then
        wait(15)
        endanim:Stop()
        veryend:Play()
        wait(5)
    else
        if veryend == true then
            veryend:Stop()
        end
    end
end

how do i fix it?

It seems like the script can't find the start object in replicatedStorage, So line 1 sets start to nil. To fix you can check if there is a misspelling in "start" and that should work. If the start object is not in replicatedStorage when the script is initialized you have to check into remote events.
